# Drupal callback function from callback function

Tags: drupal, callback

I don't know how to call function on submit... actually I've tried via many ways but nothing happens.

My code :

The first function generate textarea and submit button :

```
function custom_support_form_support_ticket_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    $form['field_niveau_liste']['und']['#ajax'] = [
        'event'    => 'change',
        'callback' => 'custom_support_ticket_ajax_form_callback',
        'wrapper'  => 'niveau_message',
        'effect'   => 'slide'
    ];
    $form['field_niveau_liste']['und']['#weight'] = -1;
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="niveau_message">';
}
```

This is the callback function for the first function :

```
function custom_support_ticket_ajax_form_callback($form, $form_state)
{
    $cas = $form['field_niveau_liste']['und']['#value'];

    switch($cas){
        case 1:
            $message = t('Ticket 1');
            break;
        case 2: 
            $message = t('Ticket 2');
            break;
        case 3:
            $message = t('Ticket 3');
            break;
        default :
            $message = 'X';
    }


        $form['niveau_message'] = [
            '#type'  => 'textarea',
            '#title' => 'message',
            '#name'  => 'message_niveau',
            '#value' => $message,
            '#weight' => -1,
        ];

        $form['niveau_message_submit'] = [
            '#type'  => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Envoyer'),
            '#weight' => 0,
            '#submit' => ['custom_support_sendMessage_callback']
        ];

    return $form;

}
```

The last one, normally, send record to database, but for now I've just die() it to see if this function is called, but it doesn't work :

```
function custom_support_sendMessage_callback()
{
    die();
}
```

Where's the mistake ?

Comment: "Hello" never appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've chosen another way. Can't explain.